# Google drive many files having same name

Tags: hard-drive, google-drive

I have a folder of photos on my pc and also have uploaded that folder to google drive. When I've added some new photos to folder and then drag and drop all photos on google drive to upload new photos, google drive uploaded all photos and created a duplicate with same name of photos which was already on drive.

Is there any way google drive ask to replace or keep duplicate like windows explorer does? Because right now it's very annoying to manage file like this.

And how can a same folder contains multiple files with exact same name?

Answer (score 5):

The name you see on Google Drive web version is not the actual file name. It's stored on the server with a different filename which is unique. If you download a folder from Google Drive as ZIP which has multiple files with the same name, when you open the ZIP archive, you'll see the individual files numbered like this:

SomeFile
SomeFile(2)
SomeFile(3)
... and so on

The best bet will be to use the Google Drive desktop app which works within Windows Explorer. That will offer you the replace or duplicate option.